# Cloud Firestore en Android regresa el error "failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}"

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

He perdido las configuraciones de mis reglas en Cloud Firestore. Traté de poner lo siguiente que encontré en la documentación oficial pero no me ha servido:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /todos/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

En donde estoy colocando el anterior código es justo en esta parte de la consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error que estoy presentando está en mi código de android ya que estoy recibiendo el siguiente error:

```
W/Firestore: (21.4.2) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(users where username == # com.google.firestore.v1.Value@15fba762
    integer_value: 0
    string_value: "elfertorr" order by __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
```

Estuve investigando sobre esta falta de permisos y fue por eso que cambié las reglas esperando que el problema se solucionara pero sigue igual sin poder establecer mi app conexión con Cloud Firestore.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El problema indica que son los permisos, aunque la configuraciòn indica que tienes los permisos necesarios.

Me parece que el problema en realidad es en el còdigo Android, revisa estos puntos:

- Asegura referenciar el nombre de la colecciòn correctamente, me parece que es case-sentitive, escribe correctamente el nombre como lo definiste.
- Asegura que la base de datos no esté vacía.
- Asegura que la consulta se realice para una colecciòn existente.

---

Es importante mencionar que en este caso el configurar de esta forma la seguridad de la base de datos no es adecuado ya que cualquiera podrìa escribir en tu base de datos:

```
allow read, write: if true;
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Ya verifiqué que todo el código en android estuviera correcto y así lo es, de hecho, siempre había estado funcionando, hasta que parece que los permisos de la base de datos caducaron. Probaré lo que me mencionas, pero ¿hay alguna forma de hacerlo y que además sea seguro?

Comment: Utilicé el código que me dejaste en las reglas de firestore y recibo este error al querer guardar: `No se pudieron guardar las reglas: Line 1: mismatched input 'allow' expecting {'function', 'import', 'service', 'rules_version'}`